# Let p be an odd prime number, and a be an integer. Prove that if a^2 ≡ 1 (mod p), then a ≡ ±1 (mod p).

Tags: linear-algebra

Not sure how to approach this. I can't apply FlT since p is not given. Can I just raise both sides to 0.5? Doesn't seem proper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If 
$$a^2 = 1\mod p,$$ then $$a^2-1=0\mod p.$$ That means $$(a+1)(a-1)=0\mod p.$$ Therefore, $p|(a+1)(a-1)$. Since $p$ is prime, what does that tell you about $a+1$ and $a-1$?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  $a^2 - 1 = (a-1)(a+1)$.